# Generalized least squares results interpretation

Tags: r, linear-regression

I checked my linear regression model (WMAN = Species, WDNE = sea surface temp) and found auto-correlation so instead, I am trying generalized least squares with the following script;

```
library(nlme)
modelwa <- gls(WMAN ~WDNE, data=dat, 
               correlation = corAR1(form=~MONTH),
               na.action=na.omit)
summary(modelwa)
```

I compared both models;

```
> library(MuMIn)
> model.sel(modelw,modelwa)
Model selection table 
        (Intrc)   WDNE class na.action  correlation df   logLik   AICc delta
modelwa   31.50 0.1874   gls   na.omit crAR1(MONTH)  4 -610.461 1229.2  0.00
modelw    11.31 0.7974    lm   na.excl               3 -658.741 1323.7 94.44
        weight
modelwa      1
modelw       0
Abbreviations:
na.action: na.excl = ‘na.exclude’
correlation: crAR1(MONTH) = ‘corAR1(~MONTH)’
Models ranked by AICc(x)
```

I believe the results suggest I should use gls as the AIC is lower.

My problem is, I have been reporting F-value/R²/p-value, but the output from the gls does not have these?

I would be very grateful if someone could assist me in interpreting these results?

```
> summary(modelwa)
Generalized least squares fit by REML
  Model: WMAN ~ WDNE 
  Data: mp2017.dat 
       AIC      BIC    logLik
  1228.923 1240.661 -610.4614

Correlation Structure: ARMA(1,0)
 Formula: ~MONTH 
 Parameter estimate(s):
     Phi1 
0.4809973 

Coefficients:
                Value Std.Error  t-value p-value
(Intercept) 31.496911  8.052339 3.911524  0.0001
WDNE         0.187419  0.091495 2.048401  0.0424

 Correlation: 
     (Intr)
WDNE -0.339

Standardized residuals:
      Min        Q1       Med        Q3       Max 
-2.023362 -1.606329 -1.210127  1.427247  3.567186 

Residual standard error: 18.85341 
Degrees of freedom: 141 total; 139 residual
>
```

Comment: I think you are off topic, if I am not mistaken then this is about statistical analysis and should be on cross validated

Answer (score 0):

I have now overcome the problem of auto-correlation so I can use `lm()`

Add lag1 of residual as an X variable to the original model. This can be done using the `slide` function in `DataCombine` package.

```
library(DataCombine)
econ_data <- data.frame(economics, resid_mod1=lmMod$residuals)
econ_data_1 <- slide(econ_data, Var="resid_mod1", 
NewVar = "lag1", slideBy = -1)
econ_data_2 <- na.omit(econ_data_1)
lmMod2 <- lm(pce ~ pop + lag1, data=econ_data_2)
```

This script can be found [here](http://r-statistics.co/Assumptions-of-Linear-Regression.html)